# Azure App Service crash due to StackOverflowException in MicrosoftInstrumentationEngine_x86.dll

Tags: azure, crash, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-application-insights-profiler

We are experiencing random Azure App Service crashes, multiple times a day. Every time the application crashes the App Service is restarted.

The application is an ASP.NET MVC 5 application running .NET Framework 4.7.
Crash monitoring is enabled and the results of the crash dumps leads us to the following exceptions:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x737DB347 (MicrosoftInstrumentationEngine_x86.dll) in w3wp.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x4DDF2FFC).

Unhandled exception at 0x73187E33 (clr.dll) in Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Metrics
```

The application uses Microsoft Application Insights SDK (latest version 2.15) and we also have the Application Insights Site Extension fully enabled on the site to use SQL Profiling, (running Pre-Installed Site Extension, version 2.8.37.4238).

My conclusions is that the exception is related to Application Insights Site Extensions, but I can't find out why and how to solve it (without fully disabling Application Insights).

Should we use either the SDK or the Site extensions instead of both? Could it be conflicts?

Have anyone else experienced similar issues?

Comment: Can you drop the entire stack trace from the exception?

Comment: From the memory dump we can't get the stack trace of the actual exception inside MicrosoftInstrumentationEngine_x86.dll, the only stack trace we have, is related to our code and it does not give any clues.

Comment: @honk did you ever figure this out? We are having similar errors.

Comment: No, I didn't find any solution to this. We ended up with disabling the site extension and used the SDK way instead.